# How to make the color in bar chart of Highstock look like in candlestick chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, volume

[image]

Can volume chart's color same as the candlestick's color above?

I tried give a color list in series with the

> colors: ['red', 'red', 'green', ...]
>
> colorByPoint: true

**Highstock source code:**

```
init: function (series, options, x) {

var point = this,
    colors;
point.series = series;
point.color = series.color; // #3445
point.applyOptions(options, x);
point.pointAttr = {};

if (series.options.colorByPoint) {
    colors = series.options.colors || series.chart.options.colors;
    point.color = point.color || colors[series.colorCounter++];
    // loop back to zero
    if (series.colorCounter === colors.length) {
        series.colorCounter = 0;
    }
}

series.chart.pointCount++;
return point;
```

}

But it did not work, because not all the points in the current screen at the same time, but the volume chart's color list is.

I did this all night,Can somebody help me?

Comment: In the Highcharts you can define color of series and [upColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.candlestick.upColor).

Comment: @SebastianBochan thank you, but my problem is volume charts didn't have that config

Comment: At this moment this is buggy, because we cannot update the grouped points and apply the color. Bug reference: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5147. So we can apply the color only when datagrouping is disabled.

Comment: @SebastianBochan thank you!